# Translate Rfc2898DeriveBytes in ruby

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, cryptography

I'm trying to translate a crypto algorithm from c# in ruby.

First step is to create a key and an iv with a key derivation function:

```
    string myTestString = "my_test_string";

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcDb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(myTestString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myTestString));

    byte[] key = rfcDb.GetBytes(16);
    byte[] iv = rfcDb.GetBytes(16);

    Console.WriteLine("key => " + Convert.ToBase64String(key)); 
    Console.WriteLine("iv =>  " + Convert.ToBase64String(iv));
```

Output:

```
key => rI9LR/UyZz5UuLQm1ujqDA==
iv =>  DDBRWmlgAdOxIkVhvgluRA==
```

In ruby I use PBKDF2 gem and try to produce same values :

```
    my_test_string = "my_test_string";
    rfc_db = PBKDF2.new(password: my_test_string, salt: my_test_string, iterations: 10000, hash_function: :sha1).bin_string

    key = rfc_db.bytes[0, 15].join
    iv = rfc_db.bytes[16, 32].join

    puts "key => " + Base64.encode64(key)
    puts "iv => " + Base64.encode64(iv)
```

Output:

```
key => NjgxNzMxNjYxNDUyMDIxMjAxNjMxOTExOTEzMjYyMTYyMTQzMTkyMTc3
iv => OTIxODYxNzkxMjc=
```

---

Update according to answer, however the results still differ:

```
string myTestString = "my_test_string";

Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcDb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(myTestString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myTestString));

byte[] key = rfcDb.GetBytes(16);
byte[] iv = rfcDb.GetBytes(16);

Console.WriteLine("key => " + OutputBytesArray(key));   
Console.WriteLine("iv =>  " + OutputBytesArray(iv));
```

Output:

```
key => 172 143 75 71 245 50 103 62 84 184 180 38 214 232 234 12 
iv =>  12 48 81 90 105 96 1 211 177 34 69 97 190 9 110 68
```

And for the Ruby code:

```
my_test_string = "my_test_string";

rfc_db = PBKDF2.new(password: my_test_string, salt: my_test_string, iterations: 10000, hash_function: :sha1, key_length: 32).bin_string

key = rfc_db.bytes[0, 16]
iv = rfc_db.bytes[16, 16]

puts "key => " + key.inspect
puts "iv => " + iv.inspect
```

Output:

```
key => [68, 173, 166, 145, 202, 120, 163, 191, 191, 32, 62, 162, 143, 192, 177, 104]
iv => [92, 186, 179, 127, 42, 221, 74, 182, 148, 87, 217, 167, 109, 62, 54, 22]
```

---

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the size of the ruby PBKDF2 key and iv? After `Base64.encode64()` the outputs are not the correct lengths. `OTIxODYxNzkxMjc=` is 13 bytes hex: `3932313836313739313237` which is not a correct length, the key is similarly incorrect. 1. The lengths are wrong: figure out why. 2. It looks like the Base64 decoded is double hex encoded which explains the non-random appearance: There are entirely to many `M` characters in the Base64. Anytime you start seeing patterns in random data there is a problem. it seems the problem is in the `join` and `encode` statements.

Comment: @zaph It's not hex, it looks just decimals. The PBKDF2 function by default only returned the hash length as well. If I'm not mistaken `bytes[0, 15]` first retrieves the bytes and *then* splices the result (giving 15 bytes :) ). See my answer for more info.

Comment: Yeah, it looked like decimal but that just seemed to crazy.

Comment: Getting the decimal string representation of the bytes, then joining them and then interpreting them again as bytes **is crazy** but there you have it. Long live strong typing, if you ask me; languages that perform tricks like these should magic themselves out of existence (\rant).

Comment: Strong typing, worth the typing IMO. With hex I can see things that just aren't as apparent in decimal represented bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 3 - [edit: now 4] - mistakes in the code:

- Most importantly and interestingly for StackOverflow, PBKDF2 is defined in Ruby to output the output size of the hash function in bytes to ensure it only runs once. However, SHA-1 outputs 160 bits while you (try to) ask for 2 * 16 = 32 bytes or 256 bits. So your IV runs out of bits.
- Secondly the encoding is wrong; `join` will simply concatenate the decimal value of the bytes it seems - I don't see why it is needed *at all*.
- When looking up how Ruby is doing the slicing, it seems that it uses `ary[start, length]` → `new_ary` or `nil`.
- Finally, your Ruby code specifies `10000` (better written as `10_000` to avoid stupid mistakes like these) instead of 1000 as iteration count (the badly defined and way too low C# default). Better update and indicate the iteration count in the C# code as well.

It may be required to set the length and call `.bytes` just once on the result, and split it *afterwards* (as the bytes seem to differ it seems that the PKBDF2 implementation is smart enough to calculate the required result only once though - personally I don't like to be dependent on implementation specifics such as these).

Comment: Note that I'm not a Ruby developer. All this is performed by just making sure that the functions do what you expect them to do. To develop any kind of secure code, you should be more vigilant. Double check.

Comment: Thanks for your input Maarten, I've updated my question

Comment: @Fred Never ever do that, you invalidate my answer by updating the question that way; it would not make sense to anybody else.

Comment: @Fred There is only one parameter that is different from the Ruby PBKDF2 constructor and the constructor in the C# code. Actually, it is missing entirely. Can you find it and see what's wrong? Feel free to edit it into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I don't see any diff : string and salt are the same, iterations is 1000 as the default for the c# class, I set sha1 as hash func like the one used bye the c# class and I specify 32 as key length because, from what I understand, calling GetBytes(16) twice is the same as calling GetBytes(32)